# django tastypie using a reverse relationship on create

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I've add the below 'payments' field as a relationship to the CheckResource.

```
class CheckResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=True)
    venue = fields.ForeignKey(VenueResource, 'venue', full=False)
    payments = fields.ToManyField('payments.api.PaymentResource',
        attribute=lambda bundle: Payment.objects.filter(check=bundle.obj),
        related_name=check,
        full=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

Everything works great on list/get, but when i try a create, I get the following error:

```
{"error_message": "getattr(): attribute name must be string", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 192, in wrapper\n response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 397, in dispatch_list\n return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 427, in dispatch\n response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1165, in post_list\n updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1784, in obj_create\n self.save_m2m(m2m_bundle)\n\n File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1942, in save_m2m\n related_mngr = getattr(bundle.obj, field_object.attribute)\n\nTypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string\n"}
```

Any clue?

Thanks!
Mark

**updated**: my PaymentResource looks like this:

```
class PaymentResource(ModelResource):
    from checks.api import CheckResource
    venue = fields.ForeignKey(VenueResource, 'venue', full=False)
    check = fields.ToOneField(CheckResource, 'check', full=False)
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is the `related_name` in your `ToManyField` definition.

[Source in the documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.related_name)

Comment: Thanks, I found my answers in the link you posted. I also had to change around the attribute value to 'payment_set'.